# Add script block after workbook save in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspose

I have the below code which will create an aspose excel file to pop up. I need a script block to execute from the javascript immediately after the download happens. The registerstartupscript is not firing in the below code.

what is wrong in this?

```
workbook.Save(HttpContext.Current.Response, "Template.xls", ContentDisposition.Attachment, new XlsSaveOptions(SaveFormat.Excel97To2003));


Page.RegisterStartupScript("alert", "<script>parent.downloadcomplete()</script>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an instance of ClientScriptManager.

```
workbook.Save(HttpContext.Current.Response, "Template.xls", ContentDisposition.Attachment, new XlsSaveOptions(SaveFormat.Excel97To2003));
// Page.RegisterStartupScript("alert", "<script>parent.downloadcomplete()</script>");

ClientScriptManager cScript = Page.ClientScript;
if (!cScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered(this.GetType(), "alert"))
{
    // Register if not done already
    string javascriptCode = "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('Download complete'); </script>";

    cScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", javascriptCode);
}
```